# write sql query to display all doctor name that starts with letter 'A' and ends with letter 'Y'

Tags: sql

i m using query as follows

```
select mname
from medication
where mname like 'A%'
  and mname like 'Y';
```

i m getting answer but not exactly the names that start with A and end with Y.

Comment: What are you getting, and can we have a sample of the data?

Answer (score 3):

% is a wild card character and it means we can have anything for that value. Suppose if you want all that start with A, then we use 'A%'. If you want all that contains word 'CODE' in it, we use '%CODE%'

```
select mname from medication where mname like 'A%Y'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also select `where mname like 'A%Y'`